# Python discord bot won't join voice channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The bot is unresponsive to any commands related to joining the voice channel. Even the `you are not in a voice channel` message is not showing up which makes me wonder if there is something wrong with my code in main.py

Here is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.command()
  async def join(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send('You are not in a voice channel!')
    voiceChannel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voiceChannel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voiceChannel)
  
  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Here is my code in main:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from replit import db
import music
from stayAlive import keep_alive

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
  asyncio.run(cogs[i].setup(client))
```

I apologise if I am missing something truly basic as I am still learning.

Comment: It appears you haven't run the bot yet

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs I most definitely have. It is active even as I am typing right now. The other basic features I put in are all working except the join command.

Comment: Which version is this on (is `add_cog` async or not?). Do other commands in the same cog (like the `disconnect`) work properly?

Comment: @EricJin `add_cog` is async. The issue stemmed from me overriding the default `on_message` and was fixed by adding  `await client.process_commands(message)` at the very end of `on_message`